# How to remove all "rc" - residual packages using command line at once?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, asus

I have an Asus Q500A with win8 and Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit; Linux kernel 3.8.0-32-generic. I have been having residual package issues which have been giving me trouble trying to reconfigure xserver-xorg-lts-raring. I tried removing all residual packages from synaptic but the following were not removed.
I've been using `sudo apt-get purge name` to remove packages one at a time, I am down to `libieee1284-3:i386` but it is too time consuming. Is there a way I can remove all of them at once, or groups of them?

Output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"`

```
rc  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386             0.10.31-1ubuntu1.2                          GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
rc  libaa1:i386                                 1.4p5-39ubuntu1                             ASCII art library
rc  libaio1:i386                                0.3.109-2ubuntu1                            Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library
rc  libao4:i386                                 1.1.0-1ubuntu2                              Cross Platform Audio Output Library
rc  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386                      1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - ASN.1 library
rc  libasound2:i386                             1.0.25-1ubuntu10.2                          shared library for ALSA applications
rc  libasyncns0:i386                            0.8-4                                       Asynchronous name service query library
rc  libatk1.0-0:i386                            2.4.0-0ubuntu1                              ATK accessibility toolkit
rc  libavahi-client3:i386                       0.6.30-5ubuntu2                             Avahi client library
rc  libavahi-common3:i386                       0.6.30-5ubuntu2                             Avahi common library
rc  libavc1394-0:i386                           0.5.3-1ubuntu2                              control IEEE 1394 audio/video devices
rc  libcaca0:i386                               0.99.beta17-2.1ubuntu2                      colour ASCII art library
rc  libcairo-gobject2:i386                      1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3                           The Cairo 2D vector graphics library (GObject library)
rc  libcairo2:i386                              1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3                           The Cairo 2D vector graphics library
rc  libcanberra-gtk0:i386                       0.28-3ubuntu3                               GTK+ helper for playing widget event sounds with libcanberra
rc  libcanberra0:i386                           0.28-3ubuntu3                               simple abstract interface for playing event sounds
rc  libcap2:i386                                1:2.22-1ubuntu3                             support for getting/setting POSIX.1e capabilities
rc  libcdparanoia0:i386                         3.10.2+debian-10ubuntu1                     audio extraction tool for sampling CDs (library)
rc  libcroco3:i386                              0.6.5-1ubuntu0.1                            Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) parsing and manipulation toolkit
rc  libcups2:i386                               1.5.3-0ubuntu8                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
rc  libcupsimage2:i386                          1.5.3-0ubuntu8                              Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Raster image library
rc  libcurl3:i386                               7.22.0-3ubuntu4.3                           Multi-protocol file transfer library (OpenSSL)
rc  libdatrie1:i386                             0.2.5-3                                     Double-array trie library
rc  libdbus-glib-1-2:i386                       0.98-1ubuntu1.1                             simple interprocess messaging system (GLib-based shared library)
rc  libdbusmenu-qt2:i386                        0.9.2-0ubuntu1                              Qt implementation of the DBusMenu protocol
rc  libdrm-nouveau2:i386                        2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3                         Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
rc  libdv4:i386                                 1.0.0-3ubuntu1                              software library for DV format digital video (runtime lib)
rc  libesd0:i386                                0.2.41-10build3                             Enlightened Sound Daemon - Shared libraries
rc  libexif12:i386                              0.6.20-2ubuntu0.1                           library to parse EXIF files
rc  libexpat1:i386                              2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.1                          XML parsing C library - runtime library
rc  libflac8:i386                               1.2.1-6                                     Free Lossless Audio Codec - runtime C library
rc  libfontconfig1:i386                         2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1                            generic font configuration library - runtime
rc  libfreetype6:i386                           2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1                            FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files
rc  libgail18:i386                              2.24.10-0ubuntu6                            GNOME Accessibility Implementation Library -- shared libraries
rc  libgconf-2-4:i386                           3.2.5-0ubuntu2                              GNOME configuration database system (shared libraries)
rc  libgcrypt11:i386                            1.5.0-3ubuntu0.2                            LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
rc  libgd2-xpm:i386                             2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2                    GD Graphics Library version 2
rc  libgdbm3:i386                               1.8.3-10                                    GNU dbm database routines (runtime version)
rc  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386                     2.26.1-1                                    GDK Pixbuf library
rc  libgif4:i386                                4.1.6-9ubuntu1                              library for GIF images (library)
rc  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386            9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
rc  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:i386             9.1.4-0ubuntu0.1~precise2                   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
rc  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                        8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                            free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
rc  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386            9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
rc  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:i386             9.1.4-0ubuntu0.1~precise2                   free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
rc  libglapi-mesa:i386                          8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                            free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
rc  libglapi-mesa-lts-quantal:i386              9.0.3-0ubuntu0.4~precise1                   free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
rc  libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:i386               9.1.4-0ubuntu0.1~precise2                   free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
rc  libglu1-mesa:i386                           8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                            Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
rc  libgnome-keyring0:i386                      3.2.2-2                                     GNOME keyring services library
rc  libgnutls26:i386                            2.12.14-5ubuntu3.5                          GNU TLS library - runtime library
rc  libgomp1:i386                               4.6.3-1ubuntu5                              GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
rc  libgpg-error0:i386                          1.10-2ubuntu1                               library for common error values and messages in GnuPG components
rc  libgphoto2-2:i386                           2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                           gphoto2 digital camera library
rc  libgphoto2-port0:i386                       2.4.13-1ubuntu1.2                           gphoto2 digital camera port library
rc  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386                       1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3                  MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
rc  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386                     1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - GSSAPI support library
rc  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386        0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1                          GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
rc  libgstreamer0.10-0:i386                     0.10.36-1ubuntu1                            Core GStreamer libraries and elements
rc  libgtk2.0-0:i386                            2.24.10-0ubuntu6                            GTK+ graphical user interface library
rc  libgudev-1.0-0:i386                         1:175-0ubuntu9.4                            GObject-based wrapper library for libudev
rc  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386                    1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - crypto library
rc  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386                   1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - Base library
rc  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386                   1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - NTLM support library
rc  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386                     1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - X509 support library
rc  libibus-1.0-0:i386                          1.4.1-3ubuntu1                              Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
rc  libice6:i386                                2:1.0.7-2build1                             X11 Inter-Client Exchange library
rc  libidn11:i386                               1.23-2                                      GNU Libidn library, implementation of IETF IDN specifications
rc  libiec61883-0:i386                          1.2.0-0.1ubuntu1                            an partial implementation of IEC 61883
rc  libieee1284-3:i386                          0.2.11-10build1                             cross-platform library for parallel port access
rc  libjack-jackd2-0:i386                       1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu2                       JACK Audio Connection Kit (libraries)
rc  libjasper1:i386                             1.900.1-13                                  JasPer JPEG-2000 runtime library
rc  libjpeg-turbo8:i386                         1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.2                    IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
rc  libjson0:i386                               0.9-1ubuntu1                                JSON manipulation library - shared library
rc  libk5crypto3:i386                           1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3                  MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
rc  libkeyutils1:i386                           1.5.2-2                                     Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
rc  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386                     1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - libraries
rc  libkrb5-3:i386                              1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3                  MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
rc  libkrb5support0:i386                        1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3                  MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
rc  liblcms1:i386                               1.19.dfsg-1ubuntu3                          Little CMS color management library
rc  libldap-2.4-2:i386                          2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.4                         OpenLDAP libraries
rc  libllvm3.0:i386                             3.0-4ubuntu1                                Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libllvm3.1:i386                             3.1-2ubuntu1~12.04.1                        Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libllvm3.2:i386                             3.2-2ubuntu5~precise1                       Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM), runtime library
rc  libltdl7:i386                               2.4.2-1ubuntu1                              A system independent dlopen wrapper for GNU libtool
rc  libmad0:i386                                0.15.1b-7ubuntu1                            MPEG audio decoder library
rc  libmikmod2:i386                             3.1.12-2                                    Portable sound library
rc  libmng1:i386                                1.0.10-3                                    Multiple-image Network Graphics library
rc  libmpg123-0:i386                            1.12.1-3.2ubuntu1                           MPEG layer 1/2/3 audio decoder -- runtime library
rc  libmysqlclient18:i386                       5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                     MySQL database client library
rc  libnspr4:i386                               4.9.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                      NetScape Portable Runtime Library
rc  libnss3:i386                                3.14.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                     Network Security Service libraries
rc  libodbc1:i386                               2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3                           ODBC library for Unix
rc  libogg0:i386                                1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1                         Ogg bitstream library
rc  libopenal1:i386                             1:1.13-4ubuntu3                             Software implementation of the OpenAL API (shared library)
rc  liborc-0.4-0:i386                           1:0.4.16-1ubuntu2                           Library of Optimized Inner Loops Runtime Compiler
rc  libosmesa6:i386                             8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                            Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
rc  libp11-kit0:i386                            0.12-2ubuntu1                               Library for loading and coordinating access to PKCS#11 modules - runtime
rc  libpango1.0-0:i386                          1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1                           Layout and rendering of internationalized text
rc  libpixman-1-0:i386                          0.24.4-1                                    pixel-manipulation library for X and cairo
rc  libproxy1:i386                              0.4.7-0ubuntu4.1                            automatic proxy configuration management library (shared)
rc  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386                1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                           PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
rc  libpulse0:i386                              1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4                           PulseAudio client libraries
rc  libqt4-dbus:i386                            4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 D-Bus module
rc  libqt4-declarative:i386                     4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 Declarative module
rc  libqt4-designer:i386                        4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 designer module
rc  libqt4-network:i386                         4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 network module
rc  libqt4-opengl:i386                          4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 OpenGL module
rc  libqt4-qt3support:i386                      4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 3 compatibility library for Qt 4
rc  libqt4-script:i386                          4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 script module
rc  libqt4-scripttools:i386                     4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 script tools module
rc  libqt4-sql:i386                             4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 SQL module
rc  libqt4-svg:i386                             4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 SVG module
rc  libqt4-test:i386                            4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 test module
rc  libqt4-xml:i386                             4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 XML module
rc  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386                     4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 XML patterns module
rc  libqtcore4:i386                             4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 core module
rc  libqtgui4:i386                              4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4                          Qt 4 GUI module
rc  libqtwebkit4:i386                           2.2.1-1ubuntu4                              Web content engine library for Qt
rc  libraw1394-11:i386                          2.0.7-1ubuntu1                              library for direct access to IEEE 1394 bus (aka FireWire)
rc  libroken18-heimdal:i386                     1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - roken support library
rc  librsvg2-2:i386                             2.36.1-0ubuntu1                             SAX-based renderer library for SVG files (runtime)
rc  librtmp0:i386                               2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1                  toolkit for RTMP streams (shared library)
rc  libsamplerate0:i386                         0.1.8-4                                     Audio sample rate conversion library
rc  libsane:i386                                1.0.22-7ubuntu1                             API library for scanners
rc  libsasl2-2:i386                             2.1.25.dfsg1-3ubuntu0.1                     Cyrus SASL - authentication abstraction library
rc  libsdl-image1.2:i386                        1.2.10-3                                    image loading library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2
rc  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386                        1.2.11-7                                    Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
rc  libsdl-net1.2:i386                          1.2.7-5                                     Network library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
rc  libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386                        2.0.9-1.1ubuntu1                            ttf library for Simple DirectMedia Layer with FreeType 2 support
rc  libsdl1.2debian:i386                        1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3                           Simple DirectMedia Layer
rc  libshout3:i386                              2.2.2-7ubuntu1                              MP3/Ogg Vorbis broadcast streaming library
rc  libsm6:i386                                 2:1.2.0-2build1                             X11 Session Management library
rc  libsndfile1:i386                            1.0.25-4                                    Library for reading/writing audio files
rc  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386                     2.38.1-1                                    HTTP library implementation in C -- GNOME support library
rc  libsoup2.4-1:i386                           2.38.1-1                                    HTTP library implementation in C -- Shared library
rc  libspeex1:i386                              1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                            The Speex codec runtime library
rc  libspeexdsp1:i386                           1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                            The Speex extended runtime library
rc  libsqlite3-0:i386                           3.7.9-2ubuntu1.1                            SQLite 3 shared library
rc  libssl0.9.8:i386                            0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.1                           SSL shared libraries
rc  libstdc++5:i386                             1:3.3.6-25ubuntu1                           The GNU Standard C++ Library v3
rc  libstdc++6:i386                             4.6.3-1ubuntu5                              GNU Standard C++ Library v3
rc  libtag1-vanilla:i386                        1.7-1ubuntu5                                audio meta-data library - vanilla flavour
rc  libtasn1-3:i386                             2.10-1ubuntu1.1                             Manage ASN.1 structures (runtime)
rc  libtdb1:i386                                1.2.9-4                                     Trivial Database - shared library
rc  libthai0:i386                               0.1.16-3                                    Thai language support library
rc  libtheora0:i386                             1.1.1+dfsg.1-3ubuntu2                       The Theora Video Compression Codec
rc  libtiff4:i386                               3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5                            Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library
rc  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386                      0~git20110809-2.1                           Texture compression library for Mesa
rc  libunistring0:i386                          0.9.3-5                                     Unicode string library for C
rc  libusb-0.1-4:i386                           2:0.1.12-20                                 userspace USB programming library
rc  libv4l-0:i386                               0.8.6-1ubuntu2                              Collection of video4linux support libraries
rc  libv4lconvert0:i386                         0.8.6-1ubuntu2                              Video4linux frame format conversion library
rc  libvisual-0.4-0:i386                        0.4.0-4                                     Audio visualization framework
rc  libvorbis0a:i386                            1.3.2-1ubuntu3                              The Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec (Decoder library)
rc  libvorbisenc2:i386                          1.3.2-1ubuntu3                              The Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec (Encoder library)
rc  libvorbisfile3:i386                         1.3.2-1ubuntu3                              The Vorbis General Audio Compression Codec (High Level API)
rc  libwavpack1:i386                            4.60.1-2                                    audio codec (lossy and lossless) - library
rc  libwind0-heimdal:i386                       1.6~git20120311.dfsg.1-2ubuntu0.1           Heimdal Kerberos - stringprep implementation
rc  libwrap0:i386                               7.6.q-21                                    Wietse Venema's TCP wrappers library
rc  libx11-6:i386                               2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2                       X11 client-side library
rc  libx11-xcb1:i386                            2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2                       Xlib/XCB interface library
rc  libxau6:i386                                1:1.0.6-4                                   X11 authorisation library
rc  libxaw7:i386                                2:1.0.9-3ubuntu1                            X11 Athena Widget library
rc  libxcb-dri2-0:i386                          1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                            X C Binding, dri2 extension
rc  libxcb-glx0:i386                            1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                            X C Binding, glx extension
rc  libxcb-render0:i386                         1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                            X C Binding, render extension
rc  libxcb-shm0:i386                            1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                            X C Binding, shm extension
rc  libxcb1:i386                                1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2                            X C Binding
rc  libxcomposite1:i386                         1:0.4.3-2build1                             X11 Composite extension library
rc  libxcursor1:i386                            1:1.1.12-1ubuntu0.1                         X cursor management library
rc  libxdamage1:i386                            1:1.1.3-2build1                             X11 damaged region extension library
rc  libxdmcp6:i386                              1:1.1.0-4                                   X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
rc  libxext6:i386                               2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1                          X11 miscellaneous extension library
rc  libxfixes3:i386                             1:5.0-4ubuntu4.1                            X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library
rc  libxft2:i386                                2.2.0-3ubuntu2                              FreeType-based font drawing library for X
rc  libxi6:i386                                 2:1.6.0-0ubuntu2.1                          X11 Input extension library
rc  libxinerama1:i386                           2:1.1.1-3ubuntu0.1                          X11 Xinerama extension library
rc  libxml2:i386                                2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.6                     GNOME XML library
rc  libxmu6:i386                                2:1.1.0-3                                   X11 miscellaneous utility library
rc  libxp6:i386                                 1:1.0.1-2ubuntu0.12.04.1                    X Printing Extension (Xprint) client library
rc  libxpm4:i386                                1:3.5.9-4                                   X11 pixmap library
rc  libxrandr2:i386                             2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.2                          X11 RandR extension library
rc  libxrender1:i386                            1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.1                          X Rendering Extension client library
rc  libxslt1.1:i386                             1.1.26-8ubuntu1.3                           XSLT 1.0 processing library - runtime library
rc  libxss1:i386                                1:1.2.1-2                                   X11 Screen Saver extension library
rc  libxt6:i386                                 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1                          X11 toolkit intrinsics library
rc  libxtst6:i386                               2:1.2.0-4ubuntu0.1                          X11 Testing -- Record extension library
rc  libxv1:i386                                 2:1.0.6-2ubuntu0.1                          X11 Video extension library
rc  libxxf86vm1:i386                            1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1                          X11 XFree86 video mode extension library
rc  odbcinst1debian2:i386                       2.2.14p2-5ubuntu3                           Support library for accessing odbc ini files
rc  skype-bin:i386                              4.2.0.11-0ubuntu0.12.04.2                   client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service - binary files
rc  sni-qt:i386                                 0.2.5-0ubuntu3                              indicator support for Qt
rc  wine-compholio:i386                         1.7.4~ubuntu12.04.1                         The Compholio Edition is a special build of the popular Wine software
rc  xaw3dg:i386                                 1.5+E-18.1ubuntu1                           Xaw3d widget set
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I give you some commands that will help you to find and remove **broken** packages and **residual** packages etc.

- To find if any **broken** packages are there:

  ```
   sudo dpkg -l | grep "^iU"
  ```
- To remove **broken** packages any of two commands will help:

  ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep "^iU" | awk '{print $2}')
  ```
- To find the **residual** packages following command will help:

  ```
   sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"
  ```

**Note:** if any package is installed without any error, the first column starts with **ii** but for **residual** package it starts with **rc**, and for **broken** it starts with **iU**. For more information about package state letters, see [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807)

- To remove all **residual** packages:

  ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/{print $2}')
  ```

I wish after knowing these commands you'll be able to solve your problems. I'll be always waiting for your reply, if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks man, that removed all of the residual packages! I will now go back to your step 4. For anyone else reading this, the step 4 is about configuring xorg :http://askubuntu.com/questions/342276/experiencing-major-issues-on-graphic-displays/344625#344625

Comment: Okay, I went through all the steps namely step 4. Everything executed without error, and I did not lose GUi this time. Still having the original issues with my keyboard shortcuts. Not sure about the mouse grabbing and ctrl key being held down yet.

Comment: I have started a new post regarding my keyboard issues.http://askubuntu.com/questions/366346/remap-keyboard-ubuntu-12-04-asus-q500a

Comment: @Saurav, is `sudo` really needed in `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"`? Even without `sudo`, the output is the same. What do you think?

Comment: @DKBose: yes both are same, since `dpkg -l` is used only for listing the packages and it can be omitted here. Thanks.

Comment: @SauravKumar `dpkg -l` just query dpkg database, there is no need to use `sudo` for that, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Why not just `apt purge` instead of `apt-get remove --purge?

Answer (score 16):

Since version 2.0 in Ubuntu [20.04](/questions/tagged/20.04) APT itself provides support for [patterns](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/apt-patterns.7.html)

```
apt purge '~c'
```

Comment: By far, the best answer. =)

Comment: For people with poor eyesight like me, it's `tilde` `small C`

Answer (score 9):

There is an easier way using `aptitude`:

To list the residual packages:

```
aptitude search ~c
```

To purge them:

```
sudo aptitude purge ~c
```

[Source](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/01/31/debian-cleanup-tip-1-get-rid-of-useless-configuration-files/)

Comment: When I do that is says "This aptitude does not have Super Cow Powers"

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 system 'aptitude search ~c' doesn't work. It says 'sh: 1: aptitude: not found'. However apt search ~c does work.

Comment: @hydroxide are you sure your using it with sudo permissions?

Comment: aptitude is not installed by default on newer ubuntu versions. So you may need to "apt install aptitude" first.

Comment: @hydroxide you likely didn't use \[tilde\]\[c\] but \[hyphen\]\[c\]. ~c (i.e., \[tilde\]\[c\]), as correctly described in the answer, does work just fine.

Comment: Any equivalent `apt` version for that command on servers where aptitude is not installed?