# Can you help me fix my broken packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I would like to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, but some broken packages are preventing upgrade success:

`grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` output:

```
Broken libwayland-client0:amd64 Conflicts on libwayland0 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.5-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 1.1.0)
Broken libunity9:amd64 Breaks on unity-common [ amd64 ] < 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 7.1.2)
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on ghostscript-cups [ amd64 ] < 9.07~dfsg2-0ubuntu3.1 > ( text )
Broken libpam-systemd:amd64 Conflicts on libpam-xdg-support [ amd64 ] < 0.2-0ubuntu2 > ( admin )
Broken libharfbuzz0a:amd64 Breaks on libharfbuzz0 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.13-1 > ( libs )
Broken libharfbuzz0a:amd64 Breaks on libharfbuzz0 [ i386 ] < 0.9.13-1 > ( libs )
Broken libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-common [ amd64 ] < 6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 7.0.7)
Broken libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:amd64 Conflicts on libunity-common [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 7.0.7)
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Conflicts on account-plugin-generic-oauth [ amd64 ] < 0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1 > ( gnome ) (< 0.10bzr13.04.30)
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Breaks on account-plugin-generic-oauth [ amd64 ] < 0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1 > ( gnome ) (< 0.10bzr13.04.30)
Broken libmutter0b:amd64 Breaks on libmutter0a [ amd64 ] < 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:amd64 Breaks on libpackagekit-glib2-14 [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-3ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (<= 0.7.6-4)
Broken apache2:amd64 Conflicts on apache2.2-common [ amd64 ] < 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 > ( httpd )
Broken chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 Conflicts on chromium-codecs-ffmpeg [ amd64 ] < 28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1 -> 29.0.1547.65-0ubuntu2 > ( universe/web )
Broken unity-scope-home:amd64 Conflicts on unity-lens-shopping [ amd64 ] < 6.8.0daily13.03.04-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libsnmp30:amd64 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ amd64 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.7ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken apache2.2-bin:amd64 Breaks on gnome-user-share [ amd64 ] < 3.0.4-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.8.0-2~)
Broken libgjs0d:amd64 Conflicts on libgjs0c [ amd64 ] < 1.34.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken unity-gtk2-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk [ amd64 ] < 12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken lib32asound2:amd64 Depends on libasound2 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1 -> 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (= 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken unity-gtk3-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk3 [ amd64 ] < 12.10.3daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken activity-log-manager:amd64 Conflicts on activity-log-manager-common [ amd64 ] < 0.9.4-0ubuntu6.2 > ( utils )
Broken libgtksourceview-3.0-0:amd64 Depends on libgtksourceview-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 3.6.3-0ubuntu1 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.7)
Broken icaclient:amd64 Depends on lib32asound2 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libs )
Broken libunity-core-6.0-5:amd64 Depends on unity-services [ amd64 ] < 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 -> 7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1)
Broken libbamf3-1:amd64 Depends on bamfdaemon [ amd64 ] < 0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1 -> 0.5.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.4.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1)
Broken apache2-bin:amd64 Conflicts on apache2.2-bin [ amd64 ] < 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 -> 2.4.6-2ubuntu2 > ( httpd ) (< 2.3~)
```

Output for cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
```

output for `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^iU" -e "^rc"`:

```
rc  ibm-lotus-cae                             8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Composite Application Editor
rc  ibm-lotus-cae-nl1                         8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus CAE NL1
rc  ibm-lotus-feedreader                      8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         Feeds for IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2
rc  ibm-lotus-feedreader-nl1                  8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Feed Reader NL1
rc  ibm-lotus-notes                           8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Notes
rc  ibm-lotus-notes-core-de                   8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Notes Native German (de)
rc  ibm-lotus-notes-nl1                       8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Notes Java NL1
rc  ibm-lotus-sametime                        8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Sametime
rc  ibm-lotus-symphony                        8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Symphony
rc  ibm-lotus-symphony-nl1                    8.5.2-20100805.0821                        i386         IBM Lotus Symphony NL1
rc  libapache2-mod-php5filter                 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2                           amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
rc  libavcodec53:amd64                        6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2                           amd64        Libav codec library
rc  libavutil51:amd64                         6:0.8.6-1ubuntu2                           amd64        Libav utility library
rc  libmotif4:amd64                           2.3.3-7ubuntu1                             amd64        Open Motif - shared libraries
rc  linux-image-3.8.0-25-generic              3.8.0-25.37                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-25-generic        3.8.0-25.37                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo apt-get check`? Also, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.

Comment: There is none for apt-get check. Adding the others now.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the information, do not use comments.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^iU" -e "^rc"` Edit your question and post the output.

Comment: I was expecting `broken` packages but you've `residual packages` Try to remove first all residual packages and then try to upgrade your system once. Use [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365965/residual-packages-ubuntu-12-04/366143#366143) to remove all residual packages and [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-one/360486#360486) to upgrade your system safely.

Comment: The only one of these I was able to remove was ibm-lotus-notes, the others were claimed to not be installed. The upgrade still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I violently force the upgrade, by editing my sources.list to only include the 13.10 update sources. Then just apt-get update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, autoremove, autoclean. Surprisingly, later the upgrade to trusty just worked with do-release-upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get -f install

See if the above command works

Comment: I already tried:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1241667  It seems that this has been reported as a bug.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. So it is a known bug and I will have to wait for a fix?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1244096  The last comment in the above link provides a possible solution.  The answer Brian Murray gives is "Reviewing the files from your upgrade attempt you seem to have enabled the xorg-edgers-ppa. This will prevent the upgrade as that PPA contains different versions of packages essential to Ubuntu. The page, https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa, contains details on to how to revert to the official Xorg packages."

Comment: Thanks, the following is suggested on that site: sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
However that ppa can not be found on my system

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade your os again so that new packages will be installed and this broken packages will be fixed.

Comment: Upgrading fails, which is my issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1241667