# Software Updater fails to upgrade to 13.10

Tags: 12.10, 13.10, upgrade, package-management

I need help upgrading from 12.10 to 13.10.

It's a little under a month to 14.04 but even sooner until support for 12.10 is dropped, so I decided to upgrade to 13.10 in the meantime.

I used Software Updater to upgrade, but it keeps bumping into this problem:

> Not all updates can be installed
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
>   E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>
> This can be caused by:  * Upgrading to a pre-release version of
>   Ubuntu  * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu  *
>   Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command
>   'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.

I think that I'm having a similar problem as this: [Can you help me fix my broken packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367149/can-you-help-me-fix-my-broken-packages) which is unfortunately still unresolved. So, after reading this: [How to fix the "Unable to calculate upgrade" issue when upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202730/how-to-fix-the-unable-to-calculate-upgrade-issue-when-upgrading-from-12-04-to) , I tried checking for the problem with:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

Here's the output:

```
Broken libunity9:amd64 Breaks on unity-common [ amd64 ] < 6.12.0-0ubuntu0.2 > ( gnome ) (< 7.1.2)
Broken libpam-systemd:amd64 Conflicts on libpam-xdg-support [ amd64 ] < 0.2-0ubuntu1.1 > ( admin )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libcogl9 [ amd64 ] < 1.10.4-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on ghostscript-cups [ amd64 ] < 9.06~dfsg-0ubuntu4 > ( text )
Broken libmutter0b:amd64 Breaks on libmutter0 [ amd64 ] < 3.6.3-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken packagekit:amd64 Breaks on libpackagekit-glib2-14 [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-1 > ( libs ) (<= 0.7.6-4)
Broken python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat:amd64 Conflicts on packagekit [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-1 -> 0.8.10-2ubuntu2 > ( admin )
Broken libaudit-common:amd64 Breaks on libaudit0 [ amd64 ] < 1.7.18-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Conflicts on python-uno [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.2~rc2-0ubuntu4 > ( python )
Broken im-config:amd64 Conflicts on im-switch [ amd64 ] < 1.22ubuntu2.2 -> 1.23ubuntu1 > ( universe/x11 )
Broken libgjs0d:amd64 Conflicts on libgjs0c [ amd64 ] < 1.34.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken unity-scope-home:amd64 Conflicts on unity-lens-shopping [ amd64 ] < 6.8.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken fonts-droid:amd64 Breaks on ttf-droid [ amd64 ] < 20111207+git-1ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs ) (< 1:4.2~r1-1~)
Broken libsnmp-base:amd64 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ amd64 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.5ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 5.7.2~dfsg-5)
Broken gnome-packagekit:amd64 Breaks on gnome-software-manager [ amd64 ] < 3.6.0-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (< 3.6.0-2)
Broken qemu-kvm:amd64 Conflicts on qemu-kvm-spice [ amd64 ] < 1.2.0-2012.09-0ubuntu1 > ( misc )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken unity-gtk2-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk [ amd64 ] < 12.10.2-0ubuntu1.3 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-18 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken lib32asound2:amd64 Depends on libasound2 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25-3ubuntu3.1 -> 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu6 > ( libs ) (= 1.0.25-3ubuntu3.1)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken unity-gtk3-module:amd64 Conflicts on appmenu-gtk3 [ amd64 ] < 12.10.2-0ubuntu1.3 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken osspd:amd64 Conflicts on oss-compat [ amd64 ] < 2ubuntu1 -> 4 > ( universe/sound )
Broken osspd:amd64 Conflicts on oss-compat [ i386 ] < none -> 4 > ( universe/sound )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken friends-app:amd64 Conflicts on gwibber-service [ amd64 ] < 3.6.0-0ubuntu1.1 -> 3.7.0bzr13.04.05-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/misc )
Broken libgphoto2-6-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libgphoto2-2-dev [ amd64 ] < 2.4.14-2 > ( libdevel )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-mouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-18 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken gwibber:amd64 Depends on friends-app [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.92.0+13.10.20131001.1-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken activity-log-manager:amd64 Conflicts on activity-log-manager-common [ amd64 ] < 0.9.4-0ubuntu4.2 > ( utils )
Broken gnome-update-viewer:amd64 Depends on libpackagekit-glib2-14 [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-1 > ( libs )
Broken libgtksourceview-3.0-0:amd64 Depends on libgtksourceview-3.0-common [ amd64 ] < 3.6.0-0ubuntu1 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.7)
Broken libcogl-pango0:amd64 Depends on libcogl9 [ amd64 ] < 1.10.4-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.9.6)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-4:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data [ amd64 ] < 3.6.0.1-0ubuntu2 -> 3.8.4-0ubuntu1.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.6.0.1-0ubuntu2)
Broken wine1.4-common:amd64 Depends on wine1.4 [ amd64 ] < 1.4.1-0ubuntu1 -> 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 > ( universe/otherosfs ) (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1)
Broken teamviewer7:amd64 Depends on lib32asound2 [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25-3ubuntu3.1 > ( libs )
Broken libexttextcat-1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libexttextcat-data [ amd64 ] < 3.3.1-2 -> 3.4.0-4 > ( text ) (= 3.3.1-2)
Broken libunity-core-6.0-5:amd64 Depends on unity-services [ amd64 ] < 6.12.0-0ubuntu0.2 -> 7.1.2+13.10.20131014.1-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (= 6.12.0-0ubuntu0.2)
Broken libbamf3-0:amd64 Depends on bamfdaemon [ amd64 ] < 0.3.6-0ubuntu2 -> 0.5.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.3.6-0ubuntu2)
Broken libbamf0:amd64 Depends on bamfdaemon [ amd64 ] < 0.3.6-0ubuntu2 -> 0.5.1+13.10.20131011-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 0.3.6-0ubuntu2)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse [ amd64 ] < 1:12.9.0+git20120813.dba73ceb-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-18 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse [ amd64 ] < 1:12.9.0+git20120813.dba73ceb-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-18 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse [ amd64 ] < 1:12.9.0+git20120813.dba73ceb-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-r128 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.1+git20130104.24f28a78-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-wacom:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-19 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64 Depends on xorg-input-abi-19 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libxi6:amd64 Breaks on xserver-xorg-core [ amd64 ] < 2:1.13.4~git20130508+server-1.13-branch.10c42f57-0ubuntu0ricotz~quantal -> 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2~saucy1 > ( x11 ) (< 2:1.14)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-mach64 [ amd64 ] < 6.9.4+git20130104.80e62cc1-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-trident:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sis:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-savage:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-vesa:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-s3:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-fbdev:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-neomagic:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-sisusb:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.1.99+git20130730.6a278369-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal -> 1:7.2.0-0ubuntu10 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-13 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.1.99+git20130730.6a278369-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal -> 1:7.2.0-0ubuntu10 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-fbdev [ amd64 ] < 1:0.4.3+git20120801.2edaad4a-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.906+git20131213.f350a136-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-neomagic [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.7+git20120912.bc78be1c-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.9+git20130730.300c5a32-0ubuntu0sarvatt~quantal > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-s3 [ amd64 ] < 1:0.6.5+git20120912.92d10d5d-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-savage [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.6+git20120801.3d181030-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.7+git20120801.2beb25bd-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sis [ amd64 ] < 1:0.10.7+git20120912.339fb3bc-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-sisusb [ amd64 ] < 1:0.9.6+git20120801.894814fe-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-trident [ amd64 ] < 1:1.3.6+git20120801.3098fe71-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-vesa [ amd64 ] < 1:2.3.2+git20120912.7aafaf56-0ubuntu0sarvatt > ( x11 )
```

When I was about to remove some of them with Synaptic, I noticed that they weren't appearing when I searched for them, not even if I used apt-get to remove them.

Comment: Personally I'd just accept I'm using an unsupported release until 14.04 comes out then backup and do a clean install of 14.04. But if you want to try upgrading see this question [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/107450).  The reason it does not work is 12.10 will need to be updated to 13.04 before it can be updated to 13.10 but 13.04 is not supported any more [see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: @WarrenHill Thanks for the info. I never knew that upgrades should be done with the direct previous release. Before I resort to a clean install, though, would there be problems with upgrading an older release from a live boot of the latest release?

Comment: Yes.  To keep things simple Ubuntu is designed to only update either from one release to the next or one LTS release to the next LTS. If you are going to upgrade you will need to go via 13.04 and the link in my previous comment tells you how.  But personally I'd recommend a backup of your personal data and a clean install.