# Problems with distribution upgrade

Tags: apt, log, do-release-upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, I get the following error:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

And here is part of the very long itemized dependency problems in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file:

```
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 109
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 109
Investigating (0) perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-3 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl )
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-3 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
  Considering perl-modules:amd64 3 as a solution to perl-base:amd64 5295
  Added perl-modules:amd64 to the remove list
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 5.22.1~)
  Considering perl-modules:amd64 3 as a solution to perl-base:amd64 5295
  Added perl-modules:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing perl-base:amd64 via remove of perl-modules:amd64
  MarkDelete perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.20.2-3 > ( perl ) FU=0
  Fixing perl-base:amd64 via remove of perl-modules:amd64
Investigating (0) findutils [ amd64 ] < 4.4.2-7 -> 4.6.0+git+20160126-2 > ( utils )
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
  Considering libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 -2 as a solution to findutils:amd64 5103
  Added libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing findutils:amd64 via remove of libpython3.4-minimal:amd64
  MarkDelete libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3 > ( python ) FU=0
Investigating (0) systemd [ amd64 ] < none -> 229-4ubuntu6 > ( admin )
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ amd64 ] < 204-5ubuntu20.19 > ( admin )
  Considering systemd-services:amd64 8 as a solution to systemd:amd64 44
  Added systemd-services:amd64 to the remove list
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering systemd-services:amd64 8 as a solution to systemd:amd64 44
  Added systemd-services:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing systemd:amd64 via remove of systemd-services:amd64
  MarkDelete systemd-services [ amd64 ] < 204-5ubuntu20.19 > ( admin ) FU=0
  Fixing systemd:amd64 via remove of systemd-services:amd64
Investigating (0) libgnutls30 [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-5 > ( libs )
  Considering libhogweed2:amd64 0 as a solution to libgnutls30:amd64 39
  Added libhogweed2:amd64 to the remove list
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-5 > ( libs )
  Considering libnettle4:amd64 0 as a solution to libgnutls30:amd64 39
  Added libnettle4:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libgnutls30:amd64 via remove of libhogweed2:amd64
  MarkDelete libhogweed2 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-5 > ( libs ) FU=0
  Fixing libgnutls30:amd64 via remove of libnettle4:amd64
  MarkDelete libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-5 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) gnome-control-center [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 -> 1:3.18.2-1ubuntu6 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-control-center1 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( libs )
  Considering libgnome-control-center1:amd64 -2 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 25
  Added libgnome-control-center1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-control-center:amd64 via remove of libgnome-control-center1:amd64
  MarkDelete libgnome-control-center1 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) gvfs-backends [ amd64 ] < 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 -> 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 > ( libs )
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Breaks on gvfs-backends-goa [ amd64 ] < 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 > ( gnome ) (< 1.27.3)
  Considering gvfs-backends-goa:amd64 -2 as a solution to gvfs-backends:amd64 20
  Added gvfs-backends-goa:amd64 to the remove list
Broken gvfs-backends:amd64 Breaks on gvfs-backends-goa [ i386 ] < none > ( none ) (< 1.27.3)
  Considering gvfs-backends-goa:amd64 -2 as a solution to gvfs-backends:amd64 20
  Added gvfs-backends-goa:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gvfs-backends:amd64 via remove of gvfs-backends-goa:amd64
  MarkDelete gvfs-backends-goa [ amd64 ] < 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 > ( gnome ) FU=0
  Fixing gvfs-backends:amd64 via remove of gvfs-backends-goa:amd64
Investigating (0) unity-control-center-faces [ amd64 ] < none -> 15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu3 > ( gnome )
Broken unity-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
  Considering gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64 -2 as a solution to unity-control-center-faces:amd64 16
  Added gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing unity-control-center-faces:amd64 via remove of gnome-control-center-shared-data:amd64
  MarkDelete gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome ) FU=0
Investigating (0) xserver-xorg-core [ amd64 ] < 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 -> 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.2 > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-modesetting [ amd64 ] < 0.8.1-1build1 > ( x11 )
  Considering xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64 -1 as a solution to xserver-xorg-core:amd64 15
  Added xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing xserver-xorg-core:amd64 via remove of xserver-xorg-video-modesetting:amd64
  MarkDelete xserver-xorg-video-modesetting [ amd64 ] < 0.8.1-1build1 > ( x11 ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libtext-charwidth-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.04-7+b3 > ( perl )
Broken libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.20.0 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering perl-base:amd64 5295 as a solution to libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 15
  Removing libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 rather than change perlapi-5.20.0:amd64
  MarkDelete libtext-charwidth-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.04-7+b3 > ( perl ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libtext-iconv-perl [ amd64 ] < 1.7-5+b2 > ( perl )
Broken libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.20.0 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering perl-base:amd64 5295 as a solution to libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 15
  Removing libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 rather than change perlapi-5.20.0:amd64
  MarkDelete libtext-iconv-perl [ amd64 ] < 1.7-5+b2 > ( perl ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libical1a [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.0.1-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libical1a:amd64 Breaks on libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
  Considering libical1:amd64 -2 as a solution to libical1a:amd64 13
  Added libical1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libical1a:amd64 via remove of libical1:amd64
  MarkDelete libical1 [ amd64 ] < 1.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libtag1v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libtag1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libtag1c2a [ amd64 ] < 1.9.1-2 > ( libs )
  Considering libtag1c2a:amd64 -2 as a solution to libtag1v5:amd64 11
  Added libtag1c2a:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libtag1v5:amd64 via remove of libtag1c2a:amd64
  MarkDelete libtag1c2a [ amd64 ] < 1.9.1-2 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libtext-wrapi18n-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.06-7 -> 0.06-7.1 > ( perl )
Broken libtext-wrapi18n-perl:amd64 Depends on libtext-charwidth-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.04-7+b3 > ( perl )
  Considering libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 15 as a solution to libtext-wrapi18n-perl:amd64 11
  MarkKeep libtext-wrapi18n-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.06-7 -> 0.06-7.1 > ( perl ) FU=0
  Removing libtext-wrapi18n-perl:amd64 rather than change libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64
  MarkDelete libtext-wrapi18n-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.06-7 -> 0.06-7.1 > ( perl ) FU=0
Investigating (0) bluez [ amd64 ] < 4.101-0ubuntu13.1 -> 5.37-0ubuntu5 > ( admin )
Broken bluez:amd64 Conflicts on bluez-alsa [ amd64 ] < 4.101-0ubuntu13.1 > ( admin )
  Considering bluez-alsa:amd64 -2 as a solution to bluez:amd64 10
  Added bluez-alsa:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing bluez:amd64 via remove of bluez-alsa:amd64
  MarkDelete bluez-alsa [ amd64 ] < 4.101-0ubuntu13.1 > ( admin ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libxapian22v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.22-2 > ( libs )
Broken libxapian22v5:amd64 Conflicts on libxapian22 [ amd64 ] < 1.2.16-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
  Considering libxapian22:amd64 -1 as a solution to libxapian22v5:amd64 9
  Added libxapian22:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libxapian22v5:amd64 via remove of libxapian22:amd64
  MarkDelete libxapian22 [ amd64 ] < 1.2.16-2ubuntu1 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libsigc++-2.0-0v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 2.6.2-1 > ( libs )
Broken libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 Conflicts on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a [ amd64 ] < 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
  Considering libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64 0 as a solution to libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 9
  Added libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 via remove of libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:amd64
  MarkDelete libsigc++-2.0-0c2a [ amd64 ] < 2.2.10-0.2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libasprintf0v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.19.7-2ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libasprintf0v5:amd64 Breaks on libasprintf0c2 [ amd64 ] < 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
  Considering libasprintf0c2:amd64 0 as a solution to libasprintf0v5:amd64 8
  Added libasprintf0c2:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libasprintf0v5:amd64 via remove of libasprintf0c2:amd64
  MarkDelete libasprintf0c2 [ amd64 ] < 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) dictionaries-common [ amd64 ] < 1.20.5 -> 1.26.3 > ( text )
Broken dictionaries-common:amd64 Depends on libtext-iconv-perl [ amd64 ] < 1.7-5+b2 > ( perl )
  Considering libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 15 as a solution to dictionaries-common:amd64 8
  MarkKeep dictionaries-common [ amd64 ] < 1.20.5 -> 1.26.3 > ( text ) FU=0
  Removing dictionaries-common:amd64 rather than change libtext-iconv-perl:amd64
  MarkDelete dictionaries-common [ amd64 ] < 1.20.5 -> 1.26.3 > ( text ) FU=0
Investigating (0) gnome-icon-theme [ amd64 ] < 3.10.0-0ubuntu2 -> 3.12.0-1ubuntu3 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken gnome-icon-theme:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-icon-theme-full [ amd64 ] < 3.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
  Considering gnome-icon-theme-full:amd64 -2 as a solution to gnome-icon-theme:amd64 8
  Added gnome-icon-theme-full:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing gnome-icon-theme:amd64 via remove of gnome-icon-theme-full:amd64
  MarkDelete gnome-icon-theme-full [ amd64 ] < 3.10.0-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libcogl20 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.22.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken libcogl20:amd64 Breaks on libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs )
  Considering libcogl15:amd64 -2 as a solution to libcogl20:amd64 7
  Added libcogl15:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libcogl20:amd64 via remove of libcogl15:amd64
  MarkDelete libcogl15 [ amd64 ] < 1.16.2-1 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) bluez-obexd [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.37-0ubuntu5 > ( admin )
Broken bluez-obexd:amd64 Conflicts on obexd-client [ amd64 ] < 0.46-1ubuntu7 > ( admin )
  Considering obexd-client:amd64 -2 as a solution to bluez-obexd:amd64 7
  Added obexd-client:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing bluez-obexd:amd64 via remove of obexd-client:amd64
  MarkDelete obexd-client [ amd64 ] < 0.46-1ubuntu7 > ( admin ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libproxy1v5 [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken libproxy1v5:amd64 Conflicts on libproxy1 [ amd64 ] < 0.4.11-0ubuntu4 > ( libs )
  Considering libproxy1:amd64 -2 as a solution to libproxy1v5:amd64 7
  Added libproxy1:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libproxy1v5:amd64 via remove of libproxy1:amd64
  MarkDelete libproxy1 [ amd64 ] < 0.4.11-0ubuntu4 > ( libs ) FU=0
Investigating (0) tracker [ amd64 ] < 0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1 -> 1.6.2-0ubuntu1 > ( universe/utils )
Broken tracker:amd64 Conflicts on tracker-utils [ amd64 ] < 0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( utils )
  Considering tracker-utils:amd64 -2 as a solution to tracker:amd64 6
  Added tracker-utils:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing tracker:amd64 via remove of tracker-utils:amd64
  MarkDelete tracker-utils [ amd64 ] < 0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( utils ) FU=0
Investigating (0) libsocket6-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.25-1+b1 > ( perl )
Broken libsocket6-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.20.0 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
  Considering perl-base:amd64 5295 as a solution to libsocket6-perl:amd64 5
  Removing libsocket6-perl:amd64 rather than change perlapi-5.20.0:amd64
  MarkDelete libsocket6-perl [ amd64 ] < 0.25-1+b1 > ( perl ) FU=0
```

Similar problems have been reported before (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127396/how-to-resolve-broken-packages-when-upgrading-from-ubuntu-13-10-to-14-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367149/can-you-help-me-fix-my-broken-packages)) but I couldn't find any convincing fixes in those threads. I have tried the standard suite of commands such as `apt-get -f install` ,`apt-get clean` `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `dpkg --configure -a`, etc., but none of these helped.

Now, seeing the large number of dependency errors, would you recommend that I do a fresh install or is there is a procedure involving reasonable number of steps that would resolve these issues?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome there have been a lot of people have trouble trying to upgrade from 14.06 to 16.04 including my self. I would recommend doing a fresh installation to avoid these issues.